# Unable to read data correctly with read.table in R -- separate records are merged together. Trying to use gsub() to fix the file without success

Tags: r, regex, gsub, read.table, regex-group

I am new in R and I am learning machine learning doing the Analytics Edge MIT course on EdX. There is an exercise in which we are called to read a dataset from here: http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k/u.item

These are ratings of movies from users.  I give you a sample of the data, although it is quite straightforward to view them on the Web:

```
    1|Toy Story (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)|0|0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0 2|GoldenEye (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(1995)|0|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0 3|Four Rooms (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Four%20Rooms%20(1995)|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0 4|Get Shorty (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Get%20Shorty%20(1995)|0|1|0|0|0|1|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

The data are to be copy-pasted into a text editor then saved as a txt file and then to be read with the following code:

```
    movies = read.table("movieLens.txt", header=FALSE, sep="|",quote="\"")
```

For testing purposes I have saved the above fragment in a text file -'test.txt'- and then tried to read it with the command:

```
    movies = read.table("test.txt", header=FALSE, sep="|",quote="\"")
```

When, I then run str() to inspect the file I am informed that all the records have been merged into one:

```
    str(movies)
    'data.frame':   1 obs. of  93 variables:
```

I experimented with the text and I observed that when I press carriage return after the end of each record the text is read correctly using the following code:

```
d = read.table("test.txt", 
               header=FALSE, sep="|",quote="\"",
               col.names=c("ID", "Title", "ReleaseDate", "VideoReleaseDate", "IMDB", "Unknown", "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Childrens", "Comedy", "Crime", "Documentary", "Drama", "Fantasy", "FilmNoir", "Horror", "Musical", "Mystery", "Romance", "SciFi", "Thriller", "War", "Western"), 
               fill=FALSE, 
               strip.white=TRUE)
```

So then I thought to use gsub() to enter \n after the end of each record.

Here I run into new troubles as I can not find a way to substitute the grouped part of the pattern.

So for example,

```
notables <- c("  Ben Franklin and Jefferson Davis")
gsub('n(\\s)F', '\n', notables)
```

returns:

```
[1] "  Be\nranklin and Jefferson Davis"
```

I would expect to return instead: "  Ben\nFranklin and Jefferson Davis", i.e. replace only the grouped part of the pattern and not the entire pattern.

So here are two issues:

1. How to read the file given the problems I described?
2. How to correct my code so that gsub() replaces only the grouped part of the regex pattern?

Answer (score 0):

An easy method is to just change the delimiter to the pipe. I just copy pasted the text into notepad and did this:

```
df = read.table(file = path, header = FALSE, sep = "|", quote = "")
```

Basically instead of looking for commas to seperate fields, it will now look for pipes. You also have to disable the quotes because there are some titles that have apostrophes `read.table` will keep looking for a second one to finish that cell.